# Copying the data above blank cell to the last blank cell before meeting the next cell contains

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me if this is possible to do?

Logic is: If ColA = 1 and ColC >=1 then it should copy the entire row and insert new row below the last blank cell before meeting the next cell that contains then 1 will become 0.

Raw:

[image: input]

Final output should be:

[image: Output]

I tried to put it as text but it doesn't seem right. the code i have for now is only this, its my first project tho. my code is still incomplete as i don't know what to do next. i tried a lot of codes but not working. here's the code:

```
Dim asd As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

For zxc = 2 To C 

If Cells(zxc, "A").Value = 1 And Cells(zxc, "C").Value >= 1 Then

asd = asd + 1

End If

Next zxc

Dim AddCountRow As Long

AddCountRow = LastRow + asd

For i = 2 To AddCountRow

Dim A As Long

A = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Value 

Dim B As Long

B = Worksheets("Sheet1"). Cells(i + 1, "D"). Value 

If A >= 1 And B >= 1 Then

Cells(i + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert

i = i + 1

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you so much guys!

Comment: Edit your question and insert the code you have so far

Comment: i already added my code tho its wrong i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different approach. Considering maybe you have data below and 
lastrow could not be reliable.

Look for the <<< Customize this >>> where I set the first cell where you have the header.

This code covers the data in the sample image:

```
Sub CopyInsertRows()

    Dim colAValue As String
    Dim colBValue As String
    Dim colCValue As String
    Dim colDValue As String

    Dim initialCell As String

    Dim rowCounter As Long

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    initialCell = "A4"

    ' Loop through all cells
    For rowCounter = 2 To Rows.Count

        If Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then

            colAValue = Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value
            colBValue = Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value
            colCValue = Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value
            colDValue = Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value

        ElseIf Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = vbNullString And Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1).EntireRow.Insert

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Value = "0"

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 2).Value = colBValue

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 3).Value = colCValue

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 4).Value = colDValue

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        End If

        If Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value = vbNullString Then

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = "0"

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value = colBValue

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 3).Value = colCValue

            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 4).Value = colDValue

            Exit For

        End If

    Next rowCounter

End Sub
```

This code covers the data in the sample linked file:

```
Sub CopyInsertRows()

    Dim sourceRow As Range

    Dim initialCell As String
    Dim dateColumnLetter As String
    Dim dateColumnNumber As Integer
    Dim rowCounter As Long

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    initialCell = "A1" ' First cell of header row
    dateColumnLetter = "AA" ' Where

    ' Get column number
    dateColumnNumber = Range(dateColumnLetter & 1).Column

    ' Loop through all cells
    For rowCounter = 2 To Rows.Count

        If Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Store row values
            Set sourceRow = Range(initialCell).Range("A" & rowCounter & ":" & dateColumnLetter & rowCounter)

        ElseIf Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, 1).Value = vbNullString And Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then

            ' Insert new row
            Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter + 1).EntireRow.Insert

            ' Duplicate source row
            Range(initialCell).Range("A" & rowCounter + 1 & ":" & dateColumnLetter & rowCounter + 1).Value = sourceRow.Value

            ' Replace first cell
            Range(initialCell).Range("A" & rowCounter + 1).Value = "0"

            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        End If

        If Range(initialCell).Cells(rowCounter, dateColumnNumber).Value = vbNullString Then

            ' Duplicate source row
            Range(initialCell).Range("A" & rowCounter & ":Y" & rowCounter).Value = sourceRow.Value

            ' Replace first cell
            Range(initialCell).Range("A" & rowCounter + 1).Value = "0"

            Exit For

        End If

    Next rowCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: the real logic is schedule line should be 1 and Delivery qty should be >1 thats the time i need to do the function. It's making me crazy haha! but really thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the code I added at the bottom of my answer and try to customize it to fit your needs. Hope it helps!

Comment: OMG!!!! You're so fast! thank you so much!!! super thank you! it worked! thank you

Comment: Sir, Im very sorry but can i ask something again? cause i really need to put as schedule line = 1 and Delivery qty >=1 to process the function i just need to be specific on it cause this is just 1 part of the whole process. i hope u can help me.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You will be inserting rows so work from the bottom up.

```
Sub addLines()

    Dim i As Long, lr As Long, n As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet5")

        'collect last data row
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'loop through the rows backwards, inserting rows and transferring values
        For i = lr To 3 Step -1
            If i = lr Or .Cells(i, "A") <> vbNullString Then
                n = Application.Match(1E+99, .Range("A:A").Resize(i - 1, 1))
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 4).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(1, 4) = .Cells(n, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value
                .Cells(i, "A") = 0
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! can i ask one thing can you explain this  n = Application.Match(1E+99, .Range("A:A").Resize(i - 1, 1)) ? just wanna know thank you superr!

Comment: It identifies the row number in column A with the last number before the current row. When you insert a new A9:D9, it identifies row 5 as the last row with a number above.

Comment: thank you so much! i really appreciate it. i'll just try to add some codes for the if function for the logic. thank you!